# GatbysJS Typography - AvenirNext - Not working on Windows / Linux

Tags: html, reactjs, fonts, gatsby

I'm coding a landing page using [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/). And i want to use the AvenirNext font on my website. So i followed the tutorial about using Typography.

My ***typography.js*** file looks like :

```
import Typography from 'typography';

const typography = new Typography({
    baseFontSize: '14px',
    headerFontFamily: [
        'AvenirNextCondensed-Medium',
        'AvenirNextCondensed-Bold',
        'AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy',
    ],
    bodyFontFamily: [
        'AvenirNextCondensed-Medium',
        'AvenirNextCondensed-Bold',
        'AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy',
    ],
});

export default typography;
```

And i'm loading it in ***gatsby-config.js*** file like :

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: 'New Landing Page',
    },
     plugins: [
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
            options: {
                pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
            },
        },
        `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
        `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    ],
};
```

I thought it would have been enough to make the font available to all system, but it is only available on mac as it is a "native" font of the system.
How can i make them available for everyone ?

(Sorry for the dull question but i can't find any helping answer out here)

Comment: Why did you choose that particular font stack?

Comment: [these] fonts are protected by copyright, choose other, free fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avenir is a commercially-licenced font. It is only available to web users if they have it installed on their system or you provide it by serving the visitor a web font.

You can get a licenced webfont for your users, for example, by signing up the the [Adobe Fonts](https://fonts.adobe.com) service (which used to be called Typekit and is a paid service, included in Creative Cloud if you already have it).

You then copy one of their code snippets from their service into your React application (or CSS file using their @import option). Note, that you should take care to include the font-loading code as high up in the stack as possible to ensure that fonts are loaded quickly.

Comment: I have found the font on github (https://github.com/potyt/fonts/tree/master/macfonts/Avenir%20Next%20Condensed) and i've imported them with typeface. Thanks for th details :+1:

Comment: @LouisLecocq I can't give you legal advice, but you should ensure that you have a full licence for the font. Self-hosting a webfont will likely be against the EULA even if you have paid for it.